# How to center align button (or any div) in Bootstrap grid column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Suppose I have a button that is inside a Bootstrap grid column. By default it is left-aligned in the column. How do I center align it? Thanks.

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Delete selected PF</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `text-center` class to the element's parent div like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-2 text-center">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Delete selected PF</button>
</div>
```

Here's a jsfiddle with the above codes: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/65sf2f66/48/

Q. What is the `text-center` class in bootstrap?

A. **`text-center`** is the default bootstrap class for centering elements within that class.